# Is $SO(n)$ a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, topological-groups

I am reading some articles about covering space in Wikipedia. It says that $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ is the universal cover of $SO(n)$ for $n>2$.

I cannot understand how people view groups as topological spaces. Does it mean that $SO(n)$ is a group with topological structure (topological group), or a fundamental group of some topological spaces?

Thanks.

Comment: $SO(n)$ is a subset of $M_{n\times n}$, the space of $n\times n$ matrices. If it's over $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$), that means there is a topology on that matrix space as $\Bbb R^{n^2}$. Subspaces inherit a topology. That's my initial intuition, at least.

Comment: Everything may be a topological space as there is always a trivial topology.

Comment: @ValerySaharov Oh! my statement in the title isn't clear. My question is how people treat such groups in algebraic topology. Therefore not trivial topology nor discrete topology is the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$SO(n)$ is a subset of the space $M(n)$ of $n \times n$ matrices. This is a real vector space of dimension $n^2$ and is given the standard topological structure on a real vector space, induced by whatever your favorite norm is.

Any subset of a topological space is a topological space with the subspace topology. $SO(n)$ is not just a topological space and a group - it's both at the same time (a *topological group*). This is a topological space whose multiplication map $\mu: G \times G \to G$ and inversion map $\iota: G \to G$ are both continuous. This is true for $SO(n)$, because matrix multiplication is continuous (it's polynomial in the entries of the matrix; and/or because you can prove by hand that in the operator norm, $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$), and inversion is continuous (it's a polynomial function in the entries of the matrix by Cramer's rule, divided by the determinant, which never vanishes ofr the matrices we're considering and is also continuous). So $SO(n)$ is a topological group in this topology.

Virtually every matrix group you can think of ($GL_n, SL_n, U(n), SU(n), Sp(n),\ldots$) is a topological group, in fact a *Lie group*, which is a group with a "smooth structure" in which you can take derivatives.

Now pick a covering map $p: \tilde G \to G$. Then any element $\tilde e \in \tilde G$ with $p(\tilde e) = e$ determines a unique topological group structure on $\tilde G$ such that $p: \tilde G \to G$ is a continuous group homomorphism. The groups you get for all the different choices of $\tilde e$ are isomorphic. Thus we obtain the universal covering group $\text{Spin}(n) \to SO(n)$ for $n>3$. (For $n = 2$ it's just the double cover, and in this case we end up having $\text{Spin}(2) \cong SO(2)$.)

Comment: As in the above answer , it's called a topological group when there are certain RELATIONSHIPS between the topology and the group structure. This kind of "compound definition " is common practice, e.g. topological vector space, ordered field, normed vector space,etc.